# Linux Patching with Ansible

Tags: linux, yum, ansible

Can you please suggest any command that will check Hosts and update with only security update using ansible

And it will be equivalated to yum update --security ?

Comment: What OS?  Yum runs on several distros, and, for example, yum security won’t work on the CentOS repos.

Answer (score 0):

If you are at a release of Ansible that supports collections then the ansible.builtin.yum has an option for security - https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/yum_module.html

If that is not possible then I think you'll have to use the shell or command modules to issue the yum command just like you'd do it on the command line.